# When assigning class name as a identifier to a variable there is a confusing behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I was playing around in Python as I am relatively new to it. Below is a snippet

```
class Person:

    version = "1.0"

    def __init__(self, name="john doe",age=25):
        self.name = name
        self.first_name = name.split()[0]
        self.second_name = name.split()[1]
        self.age = age

    def printi(self):
        print(self.name)




new_person = Person()
new_person.printi()

refPerson = Person
print(refPerson.version)
another_one = refPerson()
#another_one.version = "2.0"
print(another_one.version)
another_one.printi()
print(Person.version)
Person.version = "2.0"
print(another_one.version)
print(refPerson.version)
```

And If you notice, the class name **Person** is directly assigned to a variable **refPerson**. I was under the impression that post this assignment new class of name refPerson will be created. But when I modify the Person class attribute, I could see that the value change is reflected in the new class. What am I missing here? I just need a clear picture.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: " I was under the impression that post this assignment new class of name refPerson will be created. " Yeah, that simply is incorrect. What gave you that impression? No other object works that way in Python, assignment never copies

Comment: "Assignment never copies" is correct as long as you recognize that `foo[bar] = ...` and `foo.bar = ...` aren't *really* assignments, but method calls in disguise (because those methods *could* copy objects, though for the built-in types they don't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes are first-class objects in Python; you can pass references to them around.

`Person` is a reference to the class defined by the `class` statement. `Person()` (calling the `class` object like a function) returns an instance of that class.

Attribute lookup rules can get complicated, but for this example the following simplification will suffice. Since neither `new_person.version` nor `another_one.version` is defined, an attempt to look either one up will result in a class attribute lookup. That is, `new_person.version == type(new_person).version`.

If you create an instance attribute with the same name, it will shadow the class attribute:

```
>>> new_person.version = 3
>>> new_person.version
3
>>> type(new_person).version
"1.0"
>>> another_one.version
"1.0"
```

---

Going into more detail than you are probably ready for at this stage, `Person()` breaks down into the following calls:

1. `Person()` is equivalent to `Person.__call__(Person)`, where `__call__` is an instance method of the class `type`, of which `Person` is an instance. (That is, `type(Person)` returns `type`.)
2. `Person.__call__` calls `Person.__new__`, which returns a new instance of `Person`; call it `p`.
3. `Person.__call__` then calls `Person.__init__` with `p` as its argument.
4. Finally, `Person.__call__` returns `p`.

Comment: Thanks. So I have passed a reference of the class. So Person and refPerson refers to the same class definition. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Correct. A `class` statement is, for the most part, just a declarative syntax for calling [`type` with 3 arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type), with the added side effect of performing an assignment of the resulting class object to a name.